# Simple_HTML_dom and Curl stopped working on a server

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

I've had several scripts pull information from a different server work perfectly for about a year.

Recently, it looks like they've changed something and both simple_html_dom and curl fail to work, either resulting in a **failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!** error or simply freezing.

Sometimes, I can successfully get ONE request through, but only one. The problem is the nature of the script requires more than one request from that server.

The page I am trying to pull is http://www.ic.gc.ca/app/opic-cipo/trdmrks/srch/cntnBscSrch.do?textField1=otimo&selectField1=tmlookup_ext&useblg=bscSrch.do%3Flang%3Deng&languageDirection=f&lang=eng&submitButton=Search&selectMaxDoc=1000000&selectDocsPerPage=1000000

Would really really appreciate any help

This is the simplified version of the code which also results in the same problem:

```
<?php
require("simple_html_dom.php");

function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;
}

$link="http://www.ic.gc.ca/app/opic-cipo/trdmrks/srch/cntnBscSrch.do?textField1=otamo&selectField1=tmlookup_ext&useblg=bscSrch.do%3Flang%3Deng&languageDirection=f&lang=eng&submitButton=Search&selectMaxDoc=1000000&selectDocsPerPage=1000000";

$html = file_get_html($link);
echo "SIMPLE HTML DOM:<br>".$html;

$html = file_get_contents_curl($link);
echo "CURL:<br>".$html
?>
```

Comment: The link has error .... Tied using chrome and its not working ....

Comment: It opens fine on my end

Comment: added code to avoid classifying this as off-topic.